# NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages

Tags: jsf, primefaces

NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages I use JSF 2 (Mojarra) with PrimeFaces4.0. Obs: Everything works perfectly, but has this insistent message above; This is normal? This is an informational message or warning? Someone can help me? iam gettting message in the folowing line.Also i clean,validate the project and restart the Eclipse.

Thank you in advance, Arif

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an Eclipse quirk. Try one of the following things:

Close/reopen project.
Rightclick project > Validate.
Project > Clean... and clean selected project.
Restart Eclipse.

Comment: Then please recommend the obove as your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

This most often raises the message:

```
NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

if corresponding jar file were not included in the project.

```
 Try including **primefaces-3.5.jar** file into your WEB-INF >> lib
```

All the best.